# Setting custom HTTP headers for dojox.io.script.get

Tags: javascript, http-headers, cross-domain, jsonp, dojo

I have Javascript app using `dojox.io.script.get` to make a GET request to a data-provider domain, which is different from the domain I'm issuing the request from (therefore I am relying on JSONP). I need to issue the HTTP request along with a custom header (`myHeader`).

Here's my code:

```
var args = {
    url: 'http://datadomain/path/to/data?f=json',
    callbackParamName: "handleData",
    headers: {                    #
      "myHeader": 'blablabla'     #  <-- DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK...
    },                            #
    error: function(error){
        //handle error
    }
};
dojo.io.script.get(args);

function handleData(data){
    //do something with "data"
}
```

I tested my code out but I got an error code from the server complaining about the fact that the information that should have been in the custom header is currently missing.
I read the [`dojox.io.script.get` docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/io/script.html)) but unfortunately no light shone on me...

Now, probably it's just me missing something or misunderstanding the JSONP workflow, but then how could I perform a cross-domain data request with HTTP custom headers?

Is it definitely possible to accomplish that using the dojo framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Cookie` is a header field that is handled specially by browsers. Cookies will only be sent to domains they are set to be valid for. Even if you tried to add a `Cookie` header to request, it wouldn't be added by your browser outside the origin domain. There's no way to overcome this built-in browser behaviour as it would be a security risk.

Comment: If you want to identify the remote user outside the `same-origin-policy` you need to "replace" the default Cookie functionality with your own. E.g. send that token in a custom HTTP header.

Comment: I see your point - and thanks for specifying - but cookie misuse is a different issue: in my case, cookies are set to be valid for the domain I am addressing. Here the question is: is it possible to specifiy custom HTTP headers in `dojox.io.script.get`? I'll change my question so that it can be more meaningful.